# How to read from the Image column in sharepoint Online lists using RestAPI?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, spfx, spfx-webparts

In SP Online lists (modern experience), I've added a `Image formatting and constraints for publishing` column to the list (via site columns), it converted my modern list into classic. Also I am not able to read data from it. I always get

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The field or property 'Image' does not exist.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the thread in Q&A forum, I just answered this question:

[How to read from the Image column in sharepoint Online lists using RestAPI?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92981/how-to-read-from-the-image-column-in-sharepoint-on.html)

This is the field details in my side, named "MyImage":

[image]

Use FieldAsHtml in endpoint like this:

/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('MyList3')/items(3)/FieldValuesAsHtml

[image]

Reference:

[Sharepoint 2013 REST API limitations with site columns](https://rayudu86.blogspot.com/2015/05/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-limitations.html)

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering what is the original column name for that field? Is it called exactly "MyImage"? And when I tried, the internal column name of mine was "Image", but when I did ?$select=Image, it said the column doesn't exist. Also I noticed that by attaching this type of column to the list, it makes the list a classic mode which may not be desirable.

Comment: Also PnPjs has a method to also read this column https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#retrieving-publishingpageimage I never tested it though.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/publishing-image-fields-and-the-new-sharepoint-list-and-library/m-p/44987

Comment: My Column name is "MyImage", I will post a capture about the field details in the answer above.

Yes, it shoule be, use FieldValuesAsText, it should get the real value for publishing image field.

You can also accept as answer in Q&A forum, if it's helpful to this question :-)
Thank you :-)

Comment: Just wondering, do you know if Microsoft plans to fix this in the near future and let there be a image picker column in modern mode. Seems like this has been an issue since 2017 according to that like above.

Comment: In Modern List,there is a column type named "Picture" which can used to input image url and display in Modern List

Comment: I saw that, however that won't work for my business requirements. It has to be a file picker for images for modern lists.

Comment: Also would this work `/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('MyList3')/items(3)/FieldValuesAsHtml/MyImage`, so that you can just get the image?

Comment: With File Picker function in Modern List Column, there is no built-in feature currently.
This requirement has been submitted in UserVoice:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/32249674-upload-image-in-picture-column-type
You can upvote it and comment so that Microsoft will thinking about this requirement.

Comment: If want to only get specific field, use this endpoint:

/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('MyList3')/items(6)/FieldValuesAsHtml?$select=MyImage

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, if there is a simple api to get that image column from sharepoint online lists, why does pnpjs resort to something complex like this https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#retrieving-publishingpageimage and say we need to get it from the metadata field, plus parse it with regex to get the value out? Couldn't they just make a simple wrapper for your rest api call?

Comment: I haven't tested PnP Js, but the endpoint /_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('MyList3')/items(6)/FieldValuesAsHtml?$select=MyImage

should be the real answer for this question.

Anyway, use the endpoint above should be the easiest way and you should read this blog carefully:
https://rayudu86.blogspot.com/2015/05/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-limitations.html